# how do i transform a standard COM object into ActiveX?

Tags: com, activex

A have a working COM object. do I need to do any code/registry modifications in order to make it an ActiveX?

Ofer

Comment: It'd be useful to have a brief description as to what your COM object does -- for example, is it a COM control already? What interfaces do you support, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM objects **are** ActiveX objects. Microsoft likes to change the name of the technology every once in a while. They used to be called OLE objects. They will probably be renamed to Live something or other in the future :-)

If you want to use your COM/ActiveX object in IE, there are some interfaces you need to implement. But that is a whole other question.

Comment: I don't think thats right.  Surely you mean the other way round.  ActiveX objects are COM objects.  However to be an ActiveX there are certain interfaces that have to be implemented.